# agSetColumnFilter was getting error for server side pagination

Tags: ag-grid

agSetColumnFilter was getting error for server side pagination as **"Set Filter cannot initialise because you are using a row model that does not contain all rows in the browser. Either use a different filter type, or configure Set Filter such that you provide it with values".**

I had specified

```
enableServerSideSorting: true,
enableServerSideFilter: true,
rowModelType: 'infinite'
```

and added

```
filter: "agSetColumnFilter".
```

But still I was getting the error.

How to overcome from this issue(In react application)?

Comment: The error is pretty much self explanatory. Create a plunker or stackblitz of code sample

Answer (score 5):

When you use **rowModelType = "infinite"** ag-grid's set filter does not work.
If you want to use serverside pagination you need to set **rowModelType = "serverSide"**.
So you have to use simple column filters **Text Filter, Number Filter or Date Filter**.

Set the filter value **text** in column definition.
e.g.

```
this.state = {
      columnDefs: [{
        field: 'AtheleteName',
        filter: 'text'
      },
      {
        field: 'Age',
        filter: 'number'
      },
      {
        field: 'Date',
        filter: 'date'
      }]
}
```

Ref - [Provided simple filters](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-provided-simple/)
[Server side operations](https://www.ag-grid.com/nodejs-server-side-operations/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the set filter with server side data, but you have to implement the datasource by supplying a `values` function to your `filterParams` [see docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/filter-set/#reference-ISetFilterParams-values).

An example of how to achieve this can be found [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-set-filter-list/#asynchronous-values)

```js
const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
        {
            filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
            filterParams: {
                values: params => {
                    // async update simulated using setTimeout()
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        // fetch values from server
                        const values = getValuesFromServer();
                        // supply values to the set filter
                        params.success(values);
                    }, 3000);
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```